# Can a polynomial sized arithmetic ciruits perform integer division?

Tags: arithmetic-circuits

Can we perform integer division with a polynomial size arithmetic circuit over $\mathbb{Q}$ that takes as input the numerator and denominator?

Comment: By arithmetic circuit do you mean a circuit composed of addition and multiplication gates?

Answer (score 4):

See [Eric Allender's survey](ftp://athos.rutgers.edu/cs/pub/allender/division.eatcs.pdf) of "recent" breakthroughs (circa more than a decade ago) in the complexity of division. The bottom line is that

> Division is complete for DLOGTIME-uniform $\mathsf{TC}^0$

so in particular there is a poly-sized circuit (of constant depth) that takes $x$ and $y$ as input and produces $x/y$. Notice that this circuit doesn't even need to be arithmetic (it only needs MAJORITY gates in addition to boolean gates)